# How to initialize and pass Properties class in spring contructor

Tags: java, spring

I have following class

```
 public ConsumerGroup(Properties props) {
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));
        this.topic = props.getProperty("kafka.topic");
    }
```

in Spring xml I have

```
<bean id="kafkaConsumerGroup"
        class=" com.paypal.kafka.consumer.ConsumerGroup">
               <constructor-arg index="0" value="pass the properties class"  />
</bean>
```

Using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` only helps in passing individual property.
How can I initialize `Properties` class from properties file and the pass it to constructor as a value?

Comment: Why aren't you able to configure the consumer and topic in spring config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `util:properties` element:

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" location="classpath:com/foo/myProps.properties"/>
```

More about this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties).